# JavaEE + Maven + JavaFx

Tags: java, maven, javafx

Hi I have a JavaEE Project On Maven with jdk 1.7  and i wanted to use a few functionalities of JavaFx I wonted to know how to add the Maven depencdency in pom.xml to use javaFX?

note that i've already searched mvnrepository.com and couldn't find javafx there!
isn't it because javafx is part of jdk itself?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> Maven with jdk 1.7

Try:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javafx</groupId>
    <artifactId>jfxrt</artifactId>
    <version>${javafx.version}</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add javafx plugin in pom.xml , this should work

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>8.8.3</version>
        </plugin>
```

or  try adding dependency

```
      <dependency>
          <groupId>javafx</groupId>
          <artifactId>jfxrt</artifactId>
          <version>${javafx.version}</version>
          <type>jar</type>               
          <systemPath>${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</systemPath>
      </dependency>
```